# Sharing dependency version with NPM workspaces in monorepo

Tags: npm-install, versioning, dependency-management, npm-workspaces

We switched to NPM workspaces to share source code. Works fine.

We want to go further and utilize NPM workspaces  to share dependencies. Like every WEB app in monorepo should be built with Next.js v14.0.3 - not any other version.

How could we achieve version sharing?

Answer (score 0):

Seems we are able to define a workspace with empty `index.js` solely for the purpose of defining a dependency list, to consume it transitively:

```json
{
  "name": "@corp/static-nextjs-site",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.3",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.6",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0"
  }
}
```

and then include it into other submodules (workspaces):

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@corp/static-nextjs-site": "^0.0.1",
    ...
```

This way it is possible to share version specification in workspace managed mono-repo.